# Doing a if elseif inside a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table in my database, I have a column that stores status values for posts. So if a post is published, it's 0, draft = 1, if it's yet to be looked at by a moderator - it's 2, if it's deleted - it's 3

So table looks like:

```
postid | status
----------------
  1        0
  2        1
  3        2
```

I need to display an icon for each post based on it's status. Can I do something like this in a sql query itself instead of writing more php code:

Eg:

```
select postid as pId, status as status (if status = 0 {status = '<img src="published.png"'} elseif if status =1 {status = '<img src="draft.png"'}
```

I hope you got the idea. (The above sql statement is just for example)
Can something like this be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression, like so:

```
select 
  postid as pId, 
  CASE 
    WHEN status = 0 THEN '<img src="published.png"'
    ELSE '<img src="draft.png"' 
  END AS status
FROM table
```

Comment: Wow! Did the job. Thank you very much for this :-)